# Можно ли укоротить мой **SQL** запрос

Tags: sql

Добрый день!
Мне нужно достать продажи по всем акциям. В БД около 70 акций. 
В данное время я пишу 70 запросов))
Можно ли укоротить мой запрос?
Ниже один пример моих запросов.

```
select oa1.dept_id, COUNT(oa1.id) quantity1, sum(oa1.premium) 'sum1'
      from Table1 oa1
          Left Join Table2 od1 
          On od1.id = oa1.dept_id
      where oa1.action_ID = 1
      group by oa1.dept_id
```

Они все одинаковые запросы, там просто **ID** меняется.

Comment: Какой `ID` меняется? `oa1.action_ID`? Или какой?

Comment: @ВОРОН, да вы правы oa1.action_ID меняется.

Answer (score 1):

```
select oa1.action_ID, oa1.dept_id, COUNT(oa1.id) quantity1, sum(oa1.premium) 'sum1'
 from Table1 oa1
     Left Join Table2 od1 
     On od1.id = oa1.dept_id
 group by oa1.dept_id, oa1.action_ID
 having action_ID = 1
 order by action_ID
```

Убирать `having` если нужно выбрать все акции. Разбирать строчки для каждой из акций на стороне вызывающего кода. `order by` дописан для упрощения разбора.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ он похож на ответ приведенный ниже. Ваш ответ мне выдает все акций в строку, а мне нужно в колонках!

Comment: @ШыназАлиш ну так напишите в самом запросе что именно вам нужно. включая формат выходных данных и имена колонок. не заставляйте людей гадать. и заодно уточните что у вас за sql - ms sql, mysql, еще что-то?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  oa1.dept_id, 
  COUNT(oa1.id) quantity1, 
  sum(oa1.premium) 'sum1'
from 
  Table1 oa1
  Left Join Table2 od1 
      On od1.id = oa1.dept_id
where oa1.action_ID in (select distinct oa1.action_ID from Table1 oa1)
group by oa1.dept_id;
```

Как-то так.

Comment: Ваш ответ вселял надежды в меня, но он их не опровдал)). Мне нужно чтобы каждая акция была в отдельной колонке. То есть у меня 70 акций, и ответ должен содержать таблицу с 141 колонками)). А ваш запрос суммирует их и выводит только 3 колонки. **dept_id** не повторяеться.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто опустить "WHERE". В таком случае вы получите полную таблицу по Вашему запросу.

Comment: А если потом потребуется не повсем, а по некоторым ID? Все же лучше `in` использовать :)

Comment: эм, Ваше решение в точности повторяет действие с опущенным WHERE, т.к. обычно ID - это уникальный индекс. Если придется использовать по некоторым ID, то уж лучше организовать связь один-ко-многим и уже в связанной таблице описать, какие данные выводить.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server - может быть полезным.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите 141 столбец, то напишите 70 join'ов или 140 case'ов.
Только это вряд ли укоротит ваш запрос. :-)

Comment: Если mysql, то других решений я не вижу, а если mssql, то можно [pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177410(v=SQL.105).aspx) использовать

Answer (score 0):

для примера на 3-х акциях:

```
select oa1.dept_id, 
COUNT(case when action_ID = 1 then oa1.id end) quantity1,
sum(case when action_ID = 1 then oa1.premium end) 'sum1',
COUNT(case when action_ID = 3 then oa1.id end) quantity3, 
sum(case when action_ID = 3 then oa1.premium end) 'sum3'
COUNT(case when action_ID = 5 then oa1.id end) quantity5, 
 sum(case when action_ID = 5 then oa1.premium end) 'sum5'
      from Table1 oa1
          Left Join Table2 od1 
          On od1.id = oa1.dept_id
      where oa1.action_ID in (1,3,5)
      group by oa1.dept_id
```

Это чистый универсальный sql, но в разных субд возможно сделать pivot разными способами собрав из строк столбцы.